# C++ Regex Speed Optimize

Tags: c++, regex, pcre

hello this is my c++ regex

```
regex MyRGX(R"~((\w*)\s*[(]([^;]*)[)]\s*[;])~");
```

and this is my string

```
Data1 (

   anything1

);
```

this regex get
`Data1` and everything exists between `();` with any condition. but when i have more than 50 blocks like `Data1`, this regex search speed is going to be lower than equivalent regex in pcre. i think this regex that i have, isn't optimize for speed. do you have any suggestion to increase speed of this regex with this conditions (get everything exists between `();` and ...) ?

Comment: Your string doesn't look like a string to me.

Comment: you just think it is.

Comment: My suggestions: Use non-capturing groups (`(?:)` instead of `()`) when possible. Use `+` instead of `*` when possible (since `*` matches the empty string, there are more possible branches to explore compared to `+`). And lastly, you can use the [`optimize` flag](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) in the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex/basic_regex) to get a more optimal regex (at the cost of a slower construction). I might suggest `regex r(R"~((\w+)\s*[(]([^;]*)[)]\s*[;])~", regex_constants::optimize | regex_constants::ECMAScript);`.

Comment: Thank you but you wrong !!! you said using + but in your regex you are using * again ! please fix the regex too

Comment: I used `*` in most places because using `+` slightly modifies the grammar, and I tried to be conservative in modifying your grammar (since it's totally possible that your input strings actually need `*`). Replace all the `*` with `+` if all your strings still match that grammar. I also didn't change the capture groups to `(?:)`, again because I was trying to be conservative and I assumed you might actually want the two capture groups you have. Replace the capture groups with non-capturing groups if that's what you want. The regex in my comment isn't The Answer; it's just an illustrated example

Comment: I have to change (?:) with what in my regex? can you show it?

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected from your previous question, this looks like a case where Regex isn't the most logical solution.

"Regex" comes from "Regular Expressions" which describe "Regular Languages". And languages with matched parentheses (like C++ itself) are not regular. Now, what we call "regex" has evolved to include some non-regular languages, but that's not optimal.

In this case, it looks like a perfectly ordinary parser would work. As I understand it, the goal is to look for anything between `(` and `);`. So do a simple text search forward for `(`, backwards for `);`. Check that both are found and that `(` precedes `);`, then just use the index pair found to extract the substring.

Comment: Offer an O(N) solution which can be implemented using standard library functions, for something that provably has an O(N) bound. Get -1.